# Nested/Tree View using HTML table in Angular.js

Tags: angularjs, treeview

**View Tree Collapse and Expand Mode :**
[image: Tree View Collapse and Expand Mode]

The markup used is HTML table.

Using ng-repeat is getting tricky.

The data for each row is as below

```
{  
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Groceries",
    "price": "0",
    "total": "20",
    "parentFlag": "true",
    "parentId": "",
    childItems: [{},{}]
}
```

Using `ul` and `li` tags, we can achieve this using ng-include.

But existing app markup uses table. I am starting to think changing the markup to use `ul`,`li` and `div` is the "only" way to go. Am I missing something here? Any pointers/approaches?

Comment: Can you supply some code & view markup?  Preferably throw together a minimally functional example on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or [Plunker](http://plnkr.co).  It's hard to understand what your goals are and your current issue is without more information.

Answer (score 4):

You can try something like:

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Package</th>
            <th>Price</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat-start='Package in Packages'>
            <!-- take a look to ng-repeat-start -->
            <td>
                <button ng-click="viewChilds= !viewChilds">+</button>{{Package.name}}</td>
            <td>{{Package.total}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <!-- this is repeated for package-->
            <td colspan='2' ng-class="viewChilds? '' : 'hide'">
                <!-- viewChilds controls the collapse () -->
                <table class="subTable">
                    <!-- make some ident in subTable style -->
                    <tbody>
                        <tr ng-repeat='chilItem in Package.childItems'>
                            <!-- a nested repeat for each children -->
                            <td>{{chilItem.name}}</td>
                            <td>{{chilItem.price}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat-end></tr>
        <!-- this is repeated also (if you need) -->

    </tbody>
</table>
```

I suspect that you can figure it out. Don't forget to show the final work.

Here is a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/ENXYcu?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem few months ago and I solved it. It's a tree view table using Angular.js and bootstrap. See its code and flow to understand how it works. It has documentation with explanation and working example.

#### [GitHub link](http://github.com/chhikaradi21/tree-table)

#### [Working example on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Aditya199121/y0te91dm/1/)

## How it works?

I used simple concept to implement this table, just change your complex tree data structure to simple one dimentional array and use angular's ng-repeat to repeat this array. Each node in this array contains parent id and level info, which is used to show each node at proper place and indent it properly. eg.

```
var treeDS = [ { name : aptitude, id : 123, childNodes : [ { name :     time and work, id : 125 }, { name : problem on trains, id : 127 } ] } ]
```

Convert this tree data structure to the following one dimentional array

```
var oneDArray = [ { name : aptitude, id : 123, level : 0, indentClass : "indent-0", parentId : -1 }, { name : aptitude, id : 123, level : 0, indentClass : "indent-1" parentId : 123 }, { name : aptitude, id : 123, level : 0, indentClass : "indent-1", parentId : 123 } ]
```

This oneDArray contains all the info to show tree data structure in a table with proper parent child relationship and indentation.

level : it will show the node depth
indentClass : it will indent rows according to node depth
parentId : it will help to show which node have to show under which node.